# How to calculate packet time from latency and bandwidth

Tags: networking, communication, latency, switching, packets

I have a link between a host and a switch.

The link has a bandwidth & a latency. How to calculate the time of 2 packets(with size 1KB) to be transferred from *Host A* to *Switch 1*?

Here's the diagram(I am talking about the first link)

[image: Latency & Bandwidth]

Note: I just want to calculate it manually for these values, I want to know the principles/laws of calculating these problems.

Comment: any technology stack or languages you have in mind?

Comment: i just want to calculate it manually for these values , i want to know the principles/LAWS of calculating these problems

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Propagation time = (Frame Serialization Time) 
                  + (Link Media Delay) 
                  + (Queueing Delay) 
                  + (Node Processing Delay - if known)
```

### Formulas:

- `Frame Serialization Time = S/R`
- `Link Media Delay = D/p`
- `Queueing Delay = Q / R`
- Node processing delay is normally specified or measured

### Variable decoder:

- R: link data rate (bits/second)
- S: Packet size (bits)
- D: Link distance (meters)
- P Processing Delay (seconds)
- p: medium propagation speed (meters/second)

  - speed in copper is 210*10**6
  - speed in fiber is 300*10**6
- Q: Queue depth (bits); note: if the link is not congested, there is no Queue depth

**Applying to your question:**

I will only calculate information for the *link between Host A and Switch 1*:

```
Frame Serialization Time =  Packet_size_bits / Link_data_rate_bps
                         = 2*1024*8 / (2*10**6)
                         = 0.00819 [seconds]
Link Media Delay         = 0.04 seconds [from diagram: 40ms]
Queueing Delay           = 0.0 [assume no congestion]
Node Processing Delay    = 0.0 [Host A had nothing specified for delay]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
               Total     = 0.00819 + 0.04 + 0.0 + 0.0
                         = 0.04819 seconds
                         = 48.2 milliseconds for two 1KB packets to go from 
                                             Host A to Switch 1
```

Comment: but i don't have these parameters

Comment: @MhdSyrwan, which parameters don't you have?  Queueing delay?  Processing delay is in the same category as processing delay.  If you don't have a parameter, make the value in the equation zero

Comment: where could i put the given latency ? is it the link media delay ?

Comment: Why do we simply add Node Processing Delay to the total time? Say the file is very large, or even a stream of data, we cannot assume any buffer in the path, the sender can only send at the rate of min(Link Data Rate, Node Processing Rate).

Comment: @MikePennington is there any research paper related to your answer? I need to add reference of this formula in my work. Kindly help in this regards.

Comment: @MhdSyrwan you found this answer helpful. Can you help me in referencing this formula?

Comment: @SalmanLone I derived the formula from the theory I learned in college and my experience working with these things.

Comment: @MikePennington Thank you for the reply. Your formula is helping me in my work.

Answer (score 7):

Quite roughly, the formula is:

```
LATENCY + SIZE / THROUGHPUT<br>
In your example:<br>
LATENCY = 40ms = 0.04<br>
SIZE = 1000*2<br>
THGOUGHPUT = 2Mbps = 250,000 Bytes/second<br>
```

Bottom line:

```
0.04 + 2000 / 250000 = 0.048 = 48ms<br>
```

Notice that I converted all units to bytes and seconds, so calculations are meaningful.
This is more accurate for large packets. For small packets, real numbers are larger.

Comment: so you used the bandwidth as a throughput ?

Comment: @MhdSyrwan, use this answer at your own risk.  It does not account for frame serialization time.

Comment: but i don't have the link data rate ,how to calculate it ?

Comment: My answer is indeed quite simplistic, and doesn't take all factors in account. It should be reasonably accurate for large frames, but would be too optimistic for small ones.

Comment: here you are taking the 2 packets together not one by one ,why ?

Comment: @ugoren, Bytes != bits.  Link data speed is specified in bits per second.

Comment: @MikePennington, I know bytes!=bits. That's why 2Mbps=250,000 Bytes/second. You have to bring everything to common units before you calculate, so I chose to use bytes and seconds.

Comment: Quick question, what is SIZE in your example ? is this packetsize ?

Comment: Theoretically speak, if we put THROUGHPUT to infinite then, LATENCY + SIZE / THROUGHPUT = LATENCY + 0, which will bring the LATENCY as the only fixed bottleneck, which sounds correct! In addition if we put LATENCY to  zero, then the only bottleneck is SIZE/THROUGHPUT, will make it the only bottleneck. Queueing delay is dependent on Bandwidth per link